# CodeIgniter session data goes missing

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a project where I have used CI to build. It has an issue of session data going missing at random.

Here is my session config,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

And I have used the [Native Session](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) class which seems to have fixed this type of issue but unfortunately not. I'm not 100% sure if I have done this correctly. What I've basically done is put the code under,

**Contents of system/application/libraries/native_session.php:** inside a file called Session.php and uploaded it to the application->libraries folder. I'm auto loading the library in autoload.php like this,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(.. 'session', ...);
```

In the database table I see records with user_data and in some it's just empty.

What is being done wrong still to have session data disappear randomly?

Comment: Can you us how you add your session data to your db?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You wrote, "In the database table I see records with user_data and in some it's just empty.". What does it mean?

Comment: This http://imgur.com/ACt6VoP

Comment: Does it work without Native Session?

Comment: Native Session does not write the session to the database so I'm wondering what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the session in the autoload.php in the config folder.

```
application->config->autoload.php
```

Note you have an order to define.. it looks like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
```

Comment: I am auto loading it. I have mentioned it above.

Comment: @JanithaR: i read it but you autoloaded it in the libraries folder, and in the config exists another autoload.php file. try in this location to set the session

Comment: This is my exact line in the autload.php file `$autoload['libraries'] = array('modelresult', 'session', 'upload', 'form_validation', 'database');`